# Dynamically getting One list value with the key of another list value

Tags: list, struts2, iterator, ognl, valuestack

Dear Friends,
             I have a iterator with one list. I had another iterator inside previous iterator. I want to show first list value by the key of second list value. How to acheieve that. Please help me.

```xml
<s:iterator value="listOne" var="one">
     <s:iterator value="listsecond" var="second" status="stat">
        <s:textfield name="colDyn%{#stat.index}" value="%{one.second.name}"/>
     </s:iterator>
 </s:iterator>
```

I tried this with set tag

```xml
  <s:set value="#second.name" var="field1" scope="page"/>
  <s:textfield name="colDyn%{#stat.index}" value="%{one.#field1}"/>
```

But this gives the "key" only. But i want value of that Key..
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: The second name should be the index of he first list. Try to change the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't know exact but you have to try something like this with **trial & error**

```
<s:iterator value="listOne" var="one">
    <s:iterator value="listsecond" var="second" status="stat">

         <s:property value="#one[#second.index]" />
    </s:iterator>
     </s:iterator>
```